# What is mediaremoteagent under Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, activity-monitor, daemons

Under activity monitor there's a process called mediaremoteagent. I can't find any information about this process. What is this process and is it safe to disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mediaremoteagent is `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/Support/mediaremoteagent`

The MediaRemote framework is used for managing unified media playback across macOS, determining which app is playing media and allowing you to control the media playback using macOS. For example, supporting the Now Playing widget in Notification Center, or the play/pause/skip keys on the keyboard.

The same framework is used on iOS, for features like Control Center playback controls. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MediaRemote.framework